# Open API Generator : Generate Models in different package

Tags: go, openapi, openapi-generator

I am using Open API generator https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/usage/ to generate Golang code. But I am unable to find an option that would create schemas in a different package. The problem with the same package is if I create a persistence layer, that causes cyclic dependency if persistence is in a different package. Any clues?